# Rails Server will not run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Typing

```
$ rails server
```

in terminal on mac yields these two errors that I've tried troubleshooting by uninstalling and installing ruby & rails again and get this same error.

Typing

```
localhost:3000
```

on the browser brings a broken webpage meaning rails is not running properly.

As a complete beginner, how do i troubleshoot these problems below simply step by step to get rails to run?

```
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2
Ignoring byebug-8.2.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 8.2.2
Ignoring debug_inspector-0.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.2
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7
Ignoring mysql2-0.4.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine mysql2 --version 0.4.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.7.2
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2
Ignoring byebug-8.2.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 8.2.2
Ignoring debug_inspector-0.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.2
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7
Ignoring mysql2-0.4.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine mysql2 --version 0.4.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.7.2
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_data_typed_object_alloc
  Referenced from: /Users/Leviathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/lib/debug_inspector.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_data_typed_object_alloc
  Referenced from: /Users/Leviathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/lib/debug_inspector.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Comment: whats the output after running `ruby -v` in your terminal? Also the output of `rails -v` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT: try running `gem pristine --all` first.**

Try uninstalling and reinstalling bundler:

`gem uninstall bundler` then `gem install bundler`

Then run `bundle install`.

This will install all the gems you should have specified in your Gemfile, as well as all the extensions.

E.g `Bundle complete! 33 Gemfile dependencies, 103 gems now installed.`