# I ran bundle update now I am getting an error when I run rails s, what do I do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, nokogiri, symbols

As the title says, I ran `bundle update` and now I am getting an error, what do I do? What does this error mean and where should I be looking for a solution? Also, if you just know the solution to all of my problems and would like to tell me, that would be cool too?

Error:

```
/home/my_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby: symbol lookup error: /home/my_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so: undefined symbol: rb_data_object_alloc
```

Any help extended would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I found my answer: [StackOverFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166217/rails-server-will-not-run)

Comment: It took you 12 minutes to find the solution after asking the question. "[ask]", http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users would be a good thing to read, along with "[mcve]" and the linked pages.